# How to protect an XML based datasource?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, smartgwt

I have a GWT / SmartGWT based application, which is deployed on Google App Engine. I'm using an XML based datasource. This file is required for the application's normal operation for all users. However, I do not want non-admin users to be able to view or download this file directly by specifying its full path in the address bar. I cannot use GAE's security constraint (allow access to admins only) as mentioned below because that will render the application useless for normal users.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>ds/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

So, is there a way I can prevent users from directly accessing the file, but still allow them to use it through the application?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE (May 3, 2011):

I have data in multiple XML files and all the data is read-only (only get, no add/update/delete on these files). I have a few different functionalities on the client that use this data. Most of the times, each functionality has a separate datasource. In some cases, I have databinding with SmartGWT widgets (like ListGrid) and in others, I simply convert the data into objects and use the objects on the client.

Comment: Does the client need to access the XML file, or just server-side components?  If it's only accessed server-side, it will be unreachable from the public as long as you don't specify a static path to it in your `app.yaml`

Comment: @justin-morgan - yes, the client needs to access the data. I'm using GAE for Java, btw. I'm trying out the suggestions from Peter and will post an update soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So the file must be downloaded by the client code (javascript) but you do not want users to see it?

This can not be done - if data is available on the client then it can be accessed.

The solutions are:

1. Wrong solution: expose this data via GWT-RPC, instead via file download. GWT-RPC is hard to revers-engineer so "normal" end-users will not be able to simply download the data. However, users with some knowledge will be able to do it so this is no solution for securing sensitive data.
2. The right solution: Expose to the client only data that is needed and relevant for given user. Use GWT-RPC to access this data, or use REST if you have also other non-GWT clients. Do not expose any sensitive data. This basically forces you to implement business logic on the server instead on the client. Which is the right thing to do.

**Update:**

you should still [secure the servlet](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication):

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me take it one step at a time. Following your advice, on the client side I changed to using RestDataSource and set the URL to a new servlet. This servlet reads the XML file and sends the file content back to the client. The client is able to work with the response without any further change. Now I can secure the folder that contains the XML file. This solves part of my problem. However, as you have noted, users with some knowledge can view the response sent back from the server. Correct me if I misunderstood something so far. Continued in my next comment.

Comment: Please read the update I put on my OP. 1. For cases where I have databinding with widgets, I guess I'll have to send the entire XML file content back from the servlet, as I described in my previous comment. This would not be secure. 2. For cases where I need the objects on the client side, I could parse the XML and send the required objects back to the client. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, if you secured the servlet, then only authenticated users will be able to see this data. Additionally you could send this data via GWT-RPC which is harder to decode than REST data.

Comment: I was thinking of using GWT-RPC for #2. But for #1, I could use GWT-RPC and set the returned objects manually on the widgets, but I think I may lose out on some (SmartGWT) features which come with data binding. Please correct me if I'm missing something. Thanks for your quick response.